# Find subset of jquery-objects with specific parent

Tags: jquery

I have following selectors:

```
var $foo = $('.someClass');
var $rows = $('.rows');
$rows.each(function (index, element) {
    var $row = $(element);
    var $specificFoo = /* how to I get the specific foos, where $row is their parent */;
});
```

Any chance to do this?

For clarification:
Some `$foo` are child of `$row` - i am trying to query for this specific subset. See my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/URWkH/)

Comment: @nDudani added a paragraph for clarification - i hope this makes things clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
var foo = $('.someClass');
var rows = $('.rows');
rows.each(function (index, element) {
    var specificFoo = element.find(foo);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var $tests = $('.test');
var $divs = $('div');
$divs.each(function (index, element) {
    var $div = $(element);
    //var $test = $($tests, $divs); // won't work
    var $test = $div.find( $tests );
    alert($test.length);
});
```

This may work

Comment: thanks, but actually it is more or less the same as the answer of @ParagGajjar